# ValueError: No feature in X meets the variance threshold

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use `VarianceThreshold` and I'm getting error:

```
ValueError: No feature in X meets the variance threshold 0.16000
```

My code:

```
    from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
    sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
    sel.fit(X)
```

X has the following properties:

```
Shape =  (4898, 11)
Type: =  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells you what's wrong: none of the 10 features meets the variance requirement.  Therefore, there are no remaining features to use for fitting your data.

Since you neglected to include an *actual* example, we can't do much in the way of further diagnosis or repair.

---

Yes, you can get an empty result, but you have to catch an except that appears to be not directly documented.  If you feed `VarianceThreshold` a problem with no solution -- in that no single feature provides the required `threshold` influence on the labels -- then it throws the `ValueError` exception you got.

You convert this as you would any other such problem, with an exception handler:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold

try:
    sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
    sel.fit(X)

except ValueError:
    print("No feature is strong enough to keep")
    sel = []
```

Does this solve your problem?  I did find two examples that were buried within functions; in those instances, the function's exception handler simply used `return 0` for any exception.

Comment: I expected to get empty result, but not crash/exception. is it possible not to crash and get empty result ?